# How would you go about rendering something like a line of coke more realistically, say with shaders?

Tags: java, libgdx

Im currently developing an app, where it simulates the snorting of cocaine. Im using LibGdx in Java to do that, I have got the mechanics down, but what Im currently left with is this: [image]

Im currently rendering 1000 particles, which is doable by my Huawei P8, which isnt really high end. Doesnt really look good though. Any recommendations or other approaches you would use?

Comment: I don't know why this got a downvoted, it has broader implications for rendering fine particulate substances in general which sounds interesting to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question doesn't necessarily have to be about "cocaine" but could also relate to the rendering/animation of any sort of particle media.

You don't necessarily have to use particles to do what you want. You can just apply a decal or a texture to whatever surface you want to present the particulate material on. If you want it to animate, you can prebake something.

If you really need real time though, your best bet is going to be something with particles and some other techniques:

- You should look into something like [2D meta balls](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/exploring-metaballs-and-isosurfaces-in-2d-r2556). This would allow your particles to have the volume that you want without actually rendering more particles because of how it fills the space. The goal would be to have it feel like 10,000 grains of particulate with only 1000 particles.
- Some sort of smudging or blurring of the particles might also make it look like there's more than there really are.
- Per particle lighting will give your particles some depth and make them contrast more from each other. Similarly, some sort of global lighting might help to actually make the particulate look like it has some height (shadow on the table underneath, shadowing the back faced particles)
- Add a little bit of variation to the particles. Color, shape, and size variation will help to sell it as less of a circle particle and more of a granular substance.
- Texturing your particles might help to show some variation and possible make each particle look like more than one. Only problem with this is that movement would look very odd.

All of the above are just for the particles. You might also think about having one large solid mass and then adding particles around this to better represent the looseness of the substance while still getting the volume and the "sharpness" that you loose with something like metaballs.

I'm not an expert in engineering realistic materials so this is from my own intuition, and expert might have a better answer.

Comment: Cool, thank you for posting all the options. Would you know where I can read into per particle lighting? Cant really find a good link explaining it.

Comment: I seriously think that just adding some variation to the particles would probably work wonders.  Try adding a sorting depth so that the larger particles are behind the smaller ones.  Vary the white color every so slightly for each particle.  I think you can take those 1000 particles a lot further than what is currently depicted in the image above.  There seems to be a lot of wasted space near the center where it is just a blob of whiteness.

Comment: @zebleckDAMM The term you want to search for is "self-shadowing particles" or some variant of that. See http://www.roxlu.com/downloads/scholar/008.rendering.practical_particle_lighting.pdf